# can't change property on parent class

Tags: ios, swift

I have a view controller class:

```
class PostImageController: UIViewController {

var textToChange:String = "original"


//Action run to change the text:
@IBAction func temp(sender: AnyObject) {
    className().changeText()
    println(textToChange)
}
}
```

The goal here, is to change "original" by "new Text" from an other file containing a class.

I tried this in the class file that is called in the view controller:

```
class className: PostImageController {

func changeText() {
      super.textToChange = "New text"
}

}
```

Which does strictly nothing.

and this instead of previous exemple still in the class file:

```
override var textToChange: String {
    return "Modified !!"
}
```

which I cannot even build with because of error message:  "Cannot override mutable property with read-only property 'textToChange'".

The goal here, is to be able to change a property from a subclass file. If you have a clue why, please advise.

Answer (score 2):

use self instead of super here

```
func changeText() {
  self.textToChange = "New text"
}
```

Another solution will be to initialise textTochange in the init method of your subclass like this :

```
init() {
    super.init()
    self.textToChange = "Modified !!"
}
```

But the real problem here is that you print textToChange in the super class. Try this :

```
 @IBAction func temp(sender: AnyObject) {
      var subclassObject = className().changeText()
      println(subclassObject.textToChange)
}
```

Comment: thanks but your function, same as mine doesn't change the text and println still shows "original". As for your second proposition, I cannot build because of "cannot override with a stored property textToChange"